# Archive-path doesn’t work under ojs 3.1.2.1

Tags: ojs

Since the update of OJS to 3.1.2.1, OJS, if I want to reach the archive, throws an HTTP code 500 that the request could not be processed. There is nothing in the errorlog about this call, so I have no idea where this error occurs.

Now my question is whether this problem is already known and if so how I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the bootstrap3 plugin which was still running on an old version, an update to the new version solved the problem.